# How do I center a list?

Tags: css

I have an unordered list and I want to have it in the middle of the page.

By that, I mean that the left side bullets should be vertically aligned with the center of the list item with the longest text, but in the center of the page?

- item 1 is boring
- item 2 is a very long item indeed, oh yes it is  <=== middle char should be in center of page
- item 3 is almost as boring as item 1

and not

```
 
                 * item 1 is boring
    * item 2 is a very long item indeed, oh yes it is
           * item 3 is almost as boring as item 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer for you which centers your list with variable width: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqchen/Qh48T/). It's pure css and doesn't add any extra tags.

The method was first [published here](http://www.tightcss.com/centering/center_variable_width.htm), and should work in just about all browsers.

Comment: Errm, aplogies, but not the answer ... yet. I will award the answer when I can extrapolate it to a drop down manu. I found a few examples which work with menus with no drop-down, but i need it.

Comment: Could you give any more info (maybe even code) on how this dropdown is implemented? Is the list supposed to be the dropdown?